# Is it possible to do "something" every time linux connects to a network?

Tags: linux, wifi, networking, networkmanager

Hey, I'm trying to make a script run every time NetworkManager (or whatever, but that's what I'm talking to right now) connects to a network (or changes networks).

What I really want is, metaphorically, an init directory that fires everything inside of it whenever my wifi interface changes state/essid. Or a "network status changed" runlevel. Or something.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say what distribution you're using, but on Debian derivatives (Ubuntu, etc.) you can specify scripts to be called at various points in the setup/teardown of an interface in its config stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  You can specify scripts to be called at each of these points:

- pre-up
- up
- post-up
- down
- pre-down
- post-down

You can also drop scripts into the directories named `/etc/network/if-<stage>.d`.

For more details, see `man 5 interfaces`.

Answer (score 1):

NetworkManager has a script triggers directory called `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`. Do `man NetworkManager` to see how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the above suggestions, you could also set up an Upstart script that ran on the event wherein your network comes up.